# Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc and Fragment Identifiers

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-navigation, zend-framework-mvc

I use `Zend_Navigation` on my site.  Most of the items are `Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc` and NOT `Zend_Navigation_Page_Uri`.  I know that I can easily add a [fragment identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/intro/intro.html#fragment-uri) to a `Zend_Navigation_Page_Uri` item, but that's not the elegant solution I'm looking for.  There are a couple of solutions on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405338/how-can-i-write-zend-framework-urls-that-have-anchor-tags-in-the-body), but they extend the URL helper and don't affect navigation.

I already use a sub-classed `Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu` to render the menus. Maybe there's a way to accomplish this with the `htmlify()` function?

Comment: "but that's not the elegant solution I'm looking for" - what is the problem?

Comment: @jakenoble - I want to use fragment identifiers on `Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc` pages

Comment: Are you wanting to use Fragment Identifiers with `Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding a property called `fragment` to the page array passed into `Zend_Navigation` and then checking for it in my sub-classed `Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu::htmlify()`.  Here is my `htmlify()` code:

```
/**
 * Returns an HTML string containing an 'a' element for the given page if
 * the page's href is not empty, and a 'span' element if it is empty
 *
 * Overrides {@link Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Abstract::htmlify()}.
 *
 * @param  Zend_Navigation_Page $page  page to generate HTML for
 * @return string                      HTML string for the given page
 */
public function htmlify(Zend_Navigation_Page $page)
{
    // get label and title for translating
    $label = $page->getLabel();
    $title = $page->getTitle();

    // translate label and title?
    if ($this->getUseTranslator() && $t = $this->getTranslator()) {
        if (is_string($label) && !empty($label)) {
            $label = $t->translate($label);
        }
        if (is_string($title) && !empty($title)) {
            $title = $t->translate($title);
        }
    }

    // get attribs for element
    $attribs = array(
        'id'     => $page->getId(),
        'title'  => $title,
        'class'  => $page->getClass()
    );

    // does page have a href?
    if ($href = $page->getHref()) {
        $element = 'a';
        $attribs['href'] = $href;
        $attribs['target'] = $page->getTarget();
        // fragment identifier
        if (0 < strlen($fragment = $page->get('fragment'))) {
            $attribs['href'] .= '#' . $fragment;
        }
    } else {
        $element = 'span';
    }

    return '<' . $element . $this->_htmlAttribs($attribs) . '><span>'
         . $this->view->escape($label)
         . '</span></' . $element . '>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solutions in the [linked to post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405338/how-can-i-write-zend-framework-urls-that-have-anchor-tags-in-the-body) don't affect navigation because Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc uses Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Url and not Zend_View_Helper_Url.  You have to override Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Url::url() and then [add your helper to the helper broker](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelper.broker) for it to affect Zend_Navigation.

In my implementation, I use a '_fragment' option/param to help prevent name conflicts:

```
require_once('Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/Url.php');
class My_Controller_Action_Helper_Url extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Url
{
    public function url(array $urlOptions = array(), $name = null, $reset = false, $encode = true)
    {
        $fragment = '';
        if(isset($urlOptions['_fragment'])) {
            $fragment = '#' . $urlOptions['_fragment'];
            unset($urlOptions['_fragment']);
        }

        return parent::url($urlOptions, $name, $reset, $encode) . $fragment;
    }
}
```

Then, in the XML file I use to configure Zend_Navigation, I create a _fragment param:

```
<page>
    <id>pageId</id>
    <label>Page Label</label>
    <module>foo</module>
    <params>
        <_fragment>bar</_fragment>
    </params>
    <route>default</route>
</page>
```